# Django-CMS 500 error when clicking to add a plugin

Tags: python, django, django-cms

Hey guys, when clicking to add a new plugin ("Add Plugin" on a "Page" I get a 500 error. Using firebug I got this traceback:

```
Environment:

Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://192.168.1.10:81/admin/cms/page/1/add-plugin/
Django Version: 1.2.3
Python Version: 2.6.6
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'cms',
 'cms.plugins.text',
 'cms.plugins.picture',
 'cms.plugins.link',
 'cms.plugins.file',
 'cms.plugins.snippet',
 'cms.plugins.googlemap',
 'mptt',
 'publisher']
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'cms.middleware.page.CurrentPageMiddleware',
 'cms.middleware.user.CurrentUserMiddleware',
 'cms.middleware.media.PlaceholderMediaMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  100.                     response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  76.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  69.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in inner
  190.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django_cms-2.1.0.beta3-py2.6.egg/cms/admin/pageadmin.py" in add_plugin
  1061.                 placeholder = get_object_or_404(Placeholder, pk=placeholder_id)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/shortcuts/__init__.py" in get_object_or_404
  88.         return queryset.get(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in get
  333.         clone = self.filter(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in filter
  550.         return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in _filter_or_exclude
  568.             clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in add_q
  1128.                             can_reuse=used_aliases)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in add_filter
  1071.                 connector)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/where.py" in add
  66.             value = obj.prepare(lookup_type, value)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/where.py" in prepare
  299.             return self.field.get_prep_lookup(lookup_type, value)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py" in get_prep_lookup
  292.             return self.get_prep_value(value)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py" in get_prep_value
  479.         return int(value)

Exception Type: ValueError at /admin/cms/page/1/add-plugin/
Exception Value: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'body'
```

This is an default simple install of django-cms, all latest versions, and through python 2.6.

Comment: What's in the (webserver) error log?

Comment: Running from django's build-in server. All that shows up on the logs is a 500 error: [28/Oct/2010 13:25:53] "POST /admin/cms/page/1/add-plugin/ HTTP/1.1" 500 124857

Comment: Which version of django-cms are you using? The problem seems to arise because a string(`body`) is posted to identigy the placeholder while django-cms expects it to be an integer id!

Comment: It's the latest version pip installs.... django_cms-2.1.0.beta3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:
Upgrade from the latest pip version, to the latest version on github.